# PHP - stop character encoding auto-convertion

Tags: php, encoding

In html source
`\xE6\x82\xA0`
result is "\xE6\x82\xA0"

but in php
`<?php echo "\xE6\x82\xA0"; ?>`
result is "悠" (character for \xE6\x82\xA0 )

what can be done to make php echo `\xE6\x82\xA0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print the actual string \xE6\x82\xA0, simply replace the double quotes with single quotes. Strings in single quotes are not parsed for escape sequences.

```
<?php echo '\xE6\x82\xA0'; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping your slashes.

```
<?php echo "\\xE6\\x82\\xA0"; ?>
```

or simply use single quotes instead of double quotes

```
<?php echo '\xE6\x82\xA0'; ?>
```

or you can simply output directly

```
?>\xE6\x82\xA0<?php
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the slash characters.

```
<?php echo "\\xE6\\x82\\xA0"; ?>
```

Or write the string directly in template mode.

```
?>\xE6\x82\xA0<?php
```